# Firebase admin i cant use it with the method getCurrentUser

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

If I have this in de build.gradle `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.1'`

the method

`user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();`

stops working.

How do I solve this problem. I need the admin to list all the users in another acitivity!!

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Admin SDK does not support use an Android apps.  It's for backend code, or use in administrative programs that you run on your desktop.  Instead of using the Admin SDK in your app, you should have your app invoke a backend to get the data it needs.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users how to use this code then? I cant find a tutorial to list all the firebase users in android:(

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're trying to do.  It's not the right approach.  You need to have a backend perform that query. The Firebase client SDKs do not support listing users from Firebase Auth.  You should instead write user data to a database and query it there.

Comment: I am crying, I have a global chat, where the information of the user(email, date and message are saved), and I write it in a collection in firebase... I wish i could get all the users without writting em in realtime databas